# in_array() says array is a bool?

Tags: php

I'm struggling with an error using in_array().

In the code below I've got $active_modules as the return of a metabox.io function that gets values from an options page. This return value is an array but in_array() keeps complaining that it's not.

"Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, bool given"

I've added a second function right below this in the same file using the same array values that dumps this in an admin notice for testing. I don't understand why this works fine while the first code doesn't? Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

```php
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'WPINC' ) ) {
    die;
}

// Array of modules in plugin to be used for autoloader and settings page.
$all_modules = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 'products',
        'title' => 'Products',
        'path'  => 'kdc-products/kdc-products.php',
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 'services',
        'title' => 'Services',
        'path'  => 'kdc-services/kdc-services.php',
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 'locations',
        'title' => 'Locations',
        'path'  => 'kdc-locations/kdc-locations.php',
    ),
);

// This gives an error: Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, bool given...
$active_modules = rwmb_meta( 'modules', array( 'object_type' => 'setting' ), 'kdc-site-functions' );

foreach ( $all_modules as $module ) {
    if ( in_array( 'products', $active_modules, true ) ) {
        require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $module['path'];
    }
}

/**
 * This function works fine with the same array values as above.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function sample_admin_notice__success() {
    $all_modules    = array(
        array(
            'id'    => 'products',
            'title' => 'Products',
            'path'  => 'kdc-products/kdc-products.php',
        ),
        array(
            'id'    => 'services',
            'title' => 'Services',
            'path'  => 'kdc-services/kdc-services.php',
        ),
        array(
            'id'    => 'locations',
            'title' => 'Locations',
            'path'  => 'kdc-locations/kdc-locations.php',
        ),
    );
    $active_modules = rwmb_meta( 'modules', array( 'object_type' => 'setting' ), 'kdc-site-functions' );
    foreach ( $all_modules as $module ) {
        if ( in_array( 'products', $active_modules, true ) ) {
            $my_array[] = $module['id'];
        }
    }
    ?>
    <div class="notice">
        <p>
            <?php
                print_r( $my_array );
            ?>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'sample_admin_notice__success' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to WPSE.  I think I see your issue, but without access to the output of `rwmb_meta( 'modules', array( 'object_type' => 'setting' ), 'kdc-site-functions' )`, I cannot be sure.

Your problem appears to be that you are looping through $all_modules, but using `in_array()` to examine $active_modules.  Based on your loop, here is what I would expect to read:

```
// Because you are looping through $all_modules for $module, I assume you should use it...
foreach ( $all_modules as $module ) {
    // If I examine $module, this should not throw and error
    if ( in_array( 'products', $module, true ) ) {
        require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . $module['path'];
    }
}
```

Looking at your current code, I would assume that you are getting a failure (FALSE) value back from `rwmb_meta()`, then popping that into your `in_array()` function causes your error.

Otherwise, I would suggest you at least examine the results of your `rwmb_meta()` function, to ensure it is an array:

```
if (is_array($active_modules) && !empty($active_modules)){
    // other code here...
}
```

Hope this solves it!  Good luck.

Comment: Yep, you nailed it. I'm still learning WordPress hooks and didn't realize rwmb functionality wasn't available yet. The plugin author got back with the hook location and I got it sorted. Thanks